# JSON is unable to serialize/deserialize the default value of datatable column

Tags: c#, json, serialization, datatable

I have a datatable in which some of the columns of the datatable that in creating new rows, this default value must be placed until the user change it.
I have used JSON to serialized and deserialized the datatable for the save/load.
the serialization/deserialization using JSON successfully load the previous data in the datatable but it does not bring back the default values and they do not used in creating new rows.
is there any way to force the JSON to serialize/deserialize the default values of datatable?
thanks.
sample code is as below:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable("ff");
        DataColumn col1 = new DataColumn();
        col1.ColumnName = "dd";
        col1.DataType = typeof(bool);
        col1.DefaultValue = true;
        dt.Columns.Add(col1);
        Console.WriteLine("Before Serialization");
        Console.WriteLine(dt.NewRow()["dd"].ToString());//brings True
        string serializedStr = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dt, serializationetting);
        DataTable deserializedDt = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataTable>(serializedStr, serializationetting) as DataTable;
        deserializedDt.Rows.Add(deserializedDt.NewRow());
        Console.WriteLine("After Serialization");
        Console.WriteLine(deserializedDt.NewRow()["dd"]);//brings empty
        Console.ReadLine();

        }
        public static JsonSerializerSettings serializationetting = new JsonSerializerSettings()
        {
            TypeNameAssemblyFormat = FormatterAssemblyStyle.Full,
            TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Objects,
            Formatting = Formatting.Indented,

        };
    }

}
```

Comment: Show your code.

Comment: i have added the code.

Answer (score 0):

When you serialize, you're losing some of your default column information.  To preserve that, it seems you'd have to serialize the `DataColumn` object as well, e.g.:

```
string serializedDataCol = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(col1, serializationSetting);
```

which you could later deserialize and add back to the new `DataTable`.  I don't know that there's a way to avoid this behavior using NewtonSoft, but you could potentially create a custom contract resolver that would handle this kind of thing automatically for you on `DataTable`s, or, alternatively, you could create another class that you decorate with `DefaultValue`s that will be handled with the OOB contract resolvers.

Comment: unfortunately i have used JSON to serialized a very large class containing all of types of my user defined classes which each of them can contains a datatable also which i think that i could not do that for all of them. also some of the datatables can contain undefinite no of columns and it depends on the conditions!

Comment: Go with the custom contract resolver then, and set up your serializer/deserializer to use the custom resolver for your classes.  In there you should be able to tuck away logic to serialize and deserialize the datatables as you expect.

Comment: If possible, it might even be better to have your custom resolver simply lookup the correct defaults and set them, rather than trying to serialize all the columns as well.

Comment: can you explain more or provide me a link?

Comment: @dbc - can anyone help me on the ContractResover written for this issue in order to not affect other serialization process of the application?